# How can I access a value in my array of objects in localstorage?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, compare, local-storage

[image: Local storage values]

Hello, I want learn how can I access to title value in my array of object.  When I click the "Add movie" button I want to know if the movie title is in local storage, and if there is a movie, it will alert me "Movie already exists".

Comment: Solved

const filmExists = films.filter(film => film.title === title)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access directly to the title of only one element.
You need to get all the `films` and then treat it as a regular array. Once you have it you can just [Array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) it or [Array#find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Or, you can design your schema in a different way if you plan it to grow, same way you would do with a database (which actually is ^^)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array#some` to check if there is already an object with a specific title.

```js
const arr = [{title: 'Harry Potter'}, {title: 'Hobbit'}, {title: 'Percy Jackson'}];
const titleExists = title => arr.some(x => x.title === title);
console.log(titleExists('Hobbit'));
console.log(titleExists('Who knows?'));
```